# Jquery load more on scroll

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load data from load_second.php into result div. When I scroll down on first time it loads the data from load_second.php, however, I want to keep that data and when I scroll again it should load more data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

        $('#result').load('load_second.php');

    }
});
</script>

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append the content with `load()` method. Use `get()` to retrieve the data and append it to the `div`.

```
$.get('load_second.php', function(data) {
    $('#result').append(data);
});
```

Comment: Your answer is great, but what if I need to append one or more 'result' divs? How will I do that?

Comment: *I mean Two or more results, sorry.